Need a sample request with Header and Payload information for the RISC security-token implementation
We're incorporating RISC security-event tokens into our Project and have developed an endpoint for managing these tokens. However, we're encountering difficulties testing this on our Partner stage because we're not receiving calls from Google. Could you please provide a sample request for this call? We're particularly interested in understanding how the headers should appear and whether the JWT String in the Payload will include a Key value pair, or if only the String itself will be sent. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
